# How to load "file like object", instead of filename, with kivy SoundLoader?

Tags: mongodb, kivy

I need to play a mp3 file from gridfs in mongodb. I will get a file-like object instead filename (to the system disk).

I cannot find anyway to use SoundLoader to play the file like object directly. I checked the code here https://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/core/audio.html. it seems that kivy  audio does not suppot it. Am I right? I mean, like wave module, you can open it with file like object. I prefer not to use wave because it may has issues in different OSs.

> wave.open(file[, mode])
>
> If file is a string, open the file by that
> name, otherwise treat it as a seekable file-like object.

Any other way to load the data to SouldLoader instead of filename? Many thanks.

Comment: You should be able to play a sound using any python audio module if you run it in a separate thread.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I can play mp3 files with soundloader. The issue is soundloader only read file from disk (by filename), not from the file like object. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: I traced the code. Currently, this does not support. I am thinking to add another class or somthing but it is complicated. It involved change the class loader. The problem is  -- this may require change the design of Sound and the real player provider such as SoundAvplayer need to change as well. To register a new class to load the sound seems not an easy solution as well, since the rule to select provider is by the extension of the file name.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a direct answer but could be an alternative for now. I can use GridFSBucket in GridFS to download the file in stream then save temp file to disk. Finally load by SoundLoader. With this way, it would solve the problem with large media file issue. This solution also works for image or video but require some disk storage of course.